# Capistrano deploying to system wide RVM not seeing installed Rubies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano

I'm using a system wide Ruby install on my server, and trying to deploy to a RVM gemset (like rvm use 1.9.2@gemset_name)

When I run my Cap file, Cap pukes and says a Ruby is not installed.

*However*, in reality that Ruby is installed. (The deploying user is part of the rvm group and can `rvm use` on the command line manually.)

What might I be doing wrong?

## Relevant parts of Capfile

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.

require "bundler/capistrano"
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "erb"

set(:rvm_type)          { :system }
set(:ruby_version)      { '1.9.2' }
set(:rvm_ruby_string)   { "#{ruby_version}@#{application}" }
set(:rvm_path)          { "/usr/local/rvm" }
#set(:rvm_bin_path)      { "#{rvm_path}/bin" }

before "deploy:setup",    "rvm:debug_gemset"
before "deploy:setup",    "bundle:install_gem"

namespace :rvm do
  desc "Creates gemset for application"
  task :debug_gemset do
    disable_rvm_shell do
      run "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm list rubies" do |ch, stream, data|
        if stream == :err
          logger.debug "capured output on STDERR: #{data}"
        else # stream == :out
          logger.debug "capured output on STDOUT: #{data}"
        end
      end
    end    
  end
end

# We need this so that we can install rvm first!
def disable_rvm_shell(&block)
  default_shell = self[:default_shell]
  self[:default_shell] = nil
  yield
  self[:default_shell] = default_shell
end
```

## Cap output

```
* executing `deploy:setup'
  triggering before callbacks for `deploy:setup'
* executing `rvm:debug_gemset'
* executing "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm list rubies"  # <----- ran outside of rvm-shell
  servers: ["XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"]
Password: 
  [XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] executing command
* capured output on STDOUT:
* capured output on STDOUT: rvm rubies
* capured output on STDOUT:
* ruby-1.8.7-p352 [ x86_64 ]
* capured output on STDOUT:
* ree-1.8.7-2011.03 [ x86_64 ]
* capured output on STDOUT:
* ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
*
```

Ok, awesome: 1.9.2 is installed. (This is to be expected - I installed 1.8.7, REE and 1.9.2 manually!)

But that's not all Capistrano says...

```
    command finished
  * executing `bundle:install_gem'
  * executing "gem install bundler"
    servers: ["XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"]
    [XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] executing command
 ** [out ::XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] WARN: ruby ruby-1.9.2-p290 is not installed.
```

That last line claims that 1.9.2 not installed?!!

```
 ** [out ::XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290'
*** [err ::XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] ERROR: Gemset 'MY_APP' does not exist, rvm gemset create 'MY_APP' first.
*** [err ::XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] Error: RVM was unable to use '1.9.2@MY_APP'
    command finished
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2@MY_APP' -c 'gem install bundler'" on XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

## Debugging with cap shell

Jim Gay asks, "what about debugging with cap shell?"

`rvm/capinstrano` runs commands through `rvm-shell`, which immediately goes looking for the version and gemset essentially before the command can be executed. (Thus the `disable_rvm_shell` defined earlier that we used for doing the initial `rvm list rubies`.

For example:

```
cap> which rvm
[establishing connection(s) to XX.XXX.XXX.XX]
Password: 
** [out :: XX.XXX.XXX.XX] WARN: ruby ruby-1.9.2-p290 is not installed.
** [out :: XX.XXX.XXX.XX] To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290'
*** [err :: XX.XXX.XXX.XX] ERROR: Gemset 'MY_APP' does not exist, rvm gemset create 'MY_APP' first.
*** [err :: XX.XXX.XXX.XX] Error: RVM was unable to use '1.9.2@MY_APP'
error: failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2@MY_APP' -c 'which rvm'" on XX.XXX.XXX.XX
```

## Conclusion

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but what?

Setting 1.9.2 to be the default Ruby is not an option, as I'm also going to host a 1.8.7 app on this box (ideally). This is why I'm using RVM at the system level to begin with).

I also made sure that the deploy user is in the RVM group, per the RVM documentation.

Comment: For Future Googlers: I explain exactly what's the matter, and how to fix it, in a blog post (thanks to the answer below): http://blog.wilcoxd.com/blog/2011/08/05/capistrano-system-wide-rvm-and-creating-gemsets-as-part-of-deploysetup/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This WARN about not installed ruby is a misleading msg, it should say could not find ruby@gemset pair. If you would use this command on server:

```
rvm use 1.9.2@MY_APP
```

You would see the messages in reverse order - first error that the gemset can not be found, to solve it please go to server and run:

```
rvm --create use 1.9.2@MY_APP
```

Which will create a gemset for you, if you need any more help with it please contact IRC channel #rvm on FreeNode servers.

Comment: You are correct. I created the gemset - or rather, had the Capfile create the gemset - and it worked. Annoying that the error message put me down the wrong path, but thank you for helping

Comment: have a look on rvm-capistrano for instructions how to integrate https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/#readme

Comment: I try this and it doesn't work. Im still having issues. I delineated details on your github page @mpapis

Comment: what kind of issues? open a new question describing your situation.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i just had this bomb with a patch version of ruby different.
server was running: `ruby-1.8.7-p371`
and the deploy (cap / rvm-capistrano, not sure which exactly) wanted `rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p374`.

I tried the gemset suggestion in @mpapis which was progress, but it was then that i noticed it asked me to p374.

so if in doubt, install the latest minor version of ruby.